# how to use months_between with readline function in r?

Tags: r

so recently I learned using months_between and readline()

how can I use readline() to use month_between?

I want to know how many day the user worked from the hired date(which the hiredate is fron readline()) until now + what day the hired date was

ex)
"You were hired on Wednesday and worked for 283days until now"

the example that im trying now is something like this

```
 find_day <- function(){
response <- readline(prompt='When were you hired?(XXXX-XX-XX)')
x <- Sys.Date()-as.Date(response)
y <- format(response,'%A')
print(x)
print(y)
}
```

I know there are alot of mistakes but just want to know how I can fix it

Comment: Please include a example of your data

Comment: I added my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lubridate` package will help you here.  Here is one way to perform your calculation:

```
response <- readline(prompt='When were you hired? (XXXX-XX-XX)(year-mon-day)')

response <- ymd(response)

day_of_week <- wday(response, label=TRUE, abbr=FALSE)

time_since_hire <- as.period(interval(response,now()), unit="days")

paste0("You were hired on ",day_of_week," and worked for ",day(time_since_hire)," days until now.")
```

Example output:

[1] "You were hired on Saturday and worked for 777 days until now."

(FYI `months_between` is typically an Oracle or similar SQL function.)